# Making installation file for windows application in C#.net

Tags: c#, installation

I have completed my windows application. I have used SQL Server 2008 as database server. Now, I want to prepare an installation file for my project. The Installshield is not working either. Isn't there an alternative way to prepare the installation file?? Also, I've been running the database in windows authentication mode. As I have set my laptop name as the data source, will it work after making the installation file??? I need help. Can anyone get me out of this problem???

Comment: Look into something called WiX. Quite a few tutorials out there on it.

Comment: But it works only for website. I need for a windows application

Comment: @RajivShah Jagga means [Windows Installer Xml Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/). Not Wix.com.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to create installers is the Windows Installer Xml Toolset ([Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/)). There are a lot of tutorials on the net that will help you create your installer.